# Altair Jupyterchart error 'Failed to load model class 'AnyModel' from module 'anywidget'

Tags: python-3.x, charts, jupyter, altair, vega

Trying to use the latest Jupyterchart feature from altair library. But getting error as below.

Altair Jupyterchart error ->'Failed to load model class 'AnyModel' from module 'anywidget'. Error: No version of module anywidget is registered.

Tried the sample code in website.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)
jchart = alt.JupyterChart(chart)
jchart
```

Comment: anywidget is also required to run this, used by jchart so don't need to import but must be installed. Have you installed it as well `pip install anywidget`